# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property in FBGraphRequestManager

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated Facebook login into my react native app. After successful login, I am using `GraphRequest` to fetch the user profile. But, intermittently I am seeing the below error and I am not sure why is it happening?
[image]

Below is the code for my `FacebookService.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import FBSDK from 'react-native-fbsdk'

const {
  LoginManager,
  AccessToken,
  GraphRequest,
  GraphRequestManager,
} = FBSDK;
class FacebookService {
    constructor() {
        this.requestManager = new GraphRequestManager()
    }

    loginToFacebook(callback)
    {
        LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['email','public_profile',/*'user_friends'*/]).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    alert('Login was cancelled');
                } else {
                    console.log(result)
                    alert('Login was successful with permissions: '
                    + result.grantedPermissions.toString());
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                        (data) => {
                            //console.log(data);
                            callback(data.accessToken)
                            //alert(data.accessToken.toString())
                        }
                    )
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                //callback(error)
                alert('Login failed with error: ' + error);
            }
        );
    }

    logout()
    {
        LoginManager.logOut()
    }
    async fetchProfile() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = new GraphRequest(
            '/me',
            null,
            (error, result) => {
                if (result) {
                    const profile = result
                    profile.avatar = `https://graph.facebook.com/${result.id}/picture?type=large`
                    resolve(profile)
                } else {
                    reject(error)
                }
            }
        )

        this.requestManager.addRequest(request).start()
        })
    }
}

export const facebookService = new FacebookService()
```

And as I mentioned above, the issue is happening intermittently so I don't really know what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by removing the new instance of `this.requestManager = new GraphRequestManager()` from the constructor and adding it directly in the requestGraph like so:

```
async fetchProfile(callback) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const request = new GraphRequest(
        '/me',
        { 
          parameters: {fields: { string: 'picture.width(400),name' }}
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (result) {
            const profile = result
            //profile.avatar = `https://graph.facebook.com/${result.id}/picture?&height=400&width=400`;
            resolve(profile)
          } else {
            reject(error)
          }
        }
      )

      new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(request).start()
    })
  }
```

Let me know if this solves it for you as well. Cheers! I might experiment with using a react component and initializing GraphRequestManager in ComponentDidMount.